# How to programatically get manager instance for model in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-managers

I have a custom manager added to model like that:

```
class StandardManagerModel(models.Model):
    pass

class PublishableManager(models.Manager):
    pass

class Publishable(models.Model):
    published_objects = PublishableManager()
```

This removes the default `.objects` manager from the model. How can i retrieve a default manager declared in model class? I would like a function like `get_default_manager()`:

```
manager = get_default_manager(Publishable)
assert manager is Publishable.published_objects

manager = get_default_manager(StandardManagerModel)
assert manager is StandardManagerModel.objects
```

Comment: Most often, if you want to do that, you will keep polymorphic model by replacing objects…

`class Publishable(models.Model):` 
\n
`published_objects = PublishableManager()`\n
`objects = published_objects`

Answer (score 5):

Looks like you don't need a function at all. It's stored as an attribute on the model:

```
Model._default_manager
```

There's also `Model._base_manager`, which I can only assume is what the default manager would be if you don't provide one.

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/managers/#default-managers)

> If you use custom Manager objects, take note that the first Manager Django encounters (**in the order in which they’re defined in the model**) has a special status. Django interprets the first Manager defined in a class as the “default” Manager, and several parts of Django (including dumpdata) will use that Manager exclusively for that model. As a result, it’s a good idea to be careful in your choice of default manager in order to avoid a situation where overriding get_queryset() results in an inability to retrieve objects you’d like to work with.

You can supply the default manager as  well

```
objects = models.Manager()
published_objects = PublishableManager()
```